# git push hangs, error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413

Tags: git, gitlab

```
MUSIC@DEVs-MacBook-Air MTGCardsDataSet % git push
Enumerating objects: 1815, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1815/1815), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1811/1811), done.
error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
Writing objects: 100% (1812/1812), 715.25 MiB | 19.37 MiB/s, done.
Total 1812 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
MUSIC@DEVs-MacBook-Air MTGCardsDataSet %
```

I'm trying to push repo to my local installation of gitlab.

Comment: Based on _**solution was to use ssh, not https. gitlab behind nginx is a no go!**_ [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71245714/7758804) by the OP, I'm voting to close this as caused by a typo or not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

solution was to use ssh, not https. gitlab behind nginx is a no go!